# BlobServiceClient and BlobContainerClient options

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using nuget package azure.storage.blobs to interface with blob storage.

I start out by creating a BlobServiceClient which accepts BlobClientOptions in the constructor (so I can set retry policies etc).

[image]
Using the client I will make other calls to get the container and/or the blob. When I get the container or blob and make calls there, will those objects inherit the options also?

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connection, options);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(tileStorageEntry.ContainerName);
// Will options apply to the following call also?
containerClient.DeleteIfExistsAsync()
```

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. It may help others.